# dynamic number of gui elements in Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I want to create a gui application for android where the user will be able to add or remove fields of certain type  (4 different type of fields) to the application. Is there a way to do so in xml?

The only way I could figure to do so is by edditing the xml file from within the app which sounds as a bad idea for me.

Hope my question is clear.

Yotam.

Edit:

I have added a simple code for direct java implantation:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class Leonidas extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.counter);
        TextView TV = new TextView (this);
        TextView UV = new TextView (this);
        TV.setText("hello");
        UV.setText("goof");
        //setContentView(TV);
        //setContentView(UV);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lpars = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(UV,lpars);
        this.addContentView(TV, lpars);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Edit2:

I have searched for example and got the following working:

```
LayoutInflater inflater;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    Button b = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.alert);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final LinearLayout canvas = (LinearLayout)Leonidas.this.findViewById(R.id.counter_field);
    final View cv = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.counter,canvas,false);
    canvas.addView(cv);
}
```

Comment: If you have custom views which are defined in XML you can make them dynamically with Java using a View Inflator. I don't think it is even possible for your to edit your own XML files while you are running though. You are almost certainly going to have to create these views in java and add them to your layout instead of trying to edit layout xml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it from within your handler too (in the implementation class).

After inflating your xml layout, you respond to some kind of user interactions. 
In the handler you

- either create a new View from
  scratch, and specify its
  `layoutparams`,
- or inflate one using xml

After having the new view, you add it to the current (`this`) view, and due to its layoutparams, it will be the size, shape, color, etc. that you want.

**Update:**

If you'd like to add more complex views to your activity, it's better to write them in xml, and inflate them:

sample_component.xml: //inside res/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="0px">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/servicename_status" android:paddingLeft="15px" 
        android:paddingRight="5px"
        android:textStyle="bold" android:focusable="false" android:textSize="14px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_marginRight="3px" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lastcheck" android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="14px" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_marginRight="3px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/servicename_status" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/duration" android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="14px" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_marginRight="3px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/lastcheck" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/attempt" android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="14px" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_marginRight="3px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/duration" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/statusinfo" android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="14px" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px" android:layout_marginRight="3px" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/attempt" />
    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/alert" android:focusable="false" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:freezesText="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5px" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Inside your `Leonidas` activity class you have the handlers that have to respond to different user actions by adding/removing items to/from the view. 
Below is a sample handler of a click event, which uses `LayoutInflater`, to add the `sample_component.xml` view to your activity:

```
public final class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyClickListener()
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Leonidas .this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //  TODO: change RelativeLayout here to whatever layout 
        //  you'd like to add the new components to
        final RelativeLayout canvas = (RelativeLayout)Leonidas.this.findViewById(R.id.my_canvas);
        final View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_component, canvas, false);
        //  TODO: Look up the 5 different signatures of the addView method, 
        //  and pick that best fits your needs
        canvas.addView(childView);

        // check which button was pressed
        switch (view.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btn_prev:
                //handler for the prev button
                break;
            case R.id.btn_next:
                //handler for the next button
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that MyClickListener is implemented as an inline class within your Leonidas activity, thay's why for the `context` parameter it is used: `this.Leonidas`.

**Update**

The R.id.my_canvas would be the id of the view that you want to add components to. it is in your main.xml (or whatever xml you use for your Leonidas view).

If you put the MyClickListener class inside your Leonidas.java class (declare as inline class), it will recognize it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to search for xml inflation usage guides but couldn't find one which is clear to me.

Comment: i've just updated this answer with a small sample on inflater usage, maybe it will help you clear up things.

Comment: It helped a little bit but yet...:( First, your line Which ends Leonidas.this.findViewByID(R.layout.my_canvas) Doesn't make any sense to me or to eclipse. I tried to guess something from the autocomplete but in vain. Second, When I try to type in the Leonidas.this part eclipse says that _no enclosing instance of the type Leonidas is accessible in scope_. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. I got things working but now I got a new question. How can I tell which button has been pressed? I want to use a single click listener to decide which method to call. I assume that this is the role of the (View v) part in the code, but what can I do with it?  Thanks

Comment: You should examine the `view.getId()`. check the update for a sample

Comment: Thanks. I figured it is something of that sort but I searched for view.id in the autocomplete. One more question though, How do I the ID of a view created by inflate?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand this question. Do you need the id of a view that you inflated? like in the sample above: R.layout.my_canvas? You can specify the id inside your layout.xml's root element, or after you inflated the view, using the method `setId(int id);`

Comment: Yeah, that what I meant, thanks. How can I make sure that my ID don't collapse with the one Java set automatically?

Comment: The API Docs for `setId(int id)` says, `The identifier does not have to be unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive number.`

Comment: Cool. Not that I can see the logic in that but nevertheless, cool! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying elements in the XML, you can create them dynamically and add it to the UI. This is demonstrated in the Android Hello World Tutorial [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html#ui).

Comment: Thanks. I tried to do so but I couldn't figure how to use the addContent method. What I got is two views one ontop the other. I assume I need to set the parameter in a more "elegant" way than I did. I have attached a simple code to my original text.