# Load the another Layout xml file in to the another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-tabhost

I want to add the Another Layout in to the current Layout. . . 
I have use the TabView in My Application and now i want to change the Layout while the specific tab is clicked. and the Main TabView remain in Same Place. . 
How it is possible ??? 
Help me Please..
Thanks.

Comment: Not very clear to me. Are you trying to add new `Views` (eg. list, button, text, whatever) to your `TabView`'s current layout using existing layout xml files?

Comment: Yes, My Current Layout has the TabView and its in xml layout file.

Answer (score 2):

use 2 layouts and set the visibility to layout according to situation

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate your views on the fly from layout xmls, and them to the current layout / view.

This thread about [dynamic number of gui elements in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655347/dynamic-number-of-gui-elements-in-android/5655484#5655484) shows you how to achieve it.